# Order objects by external attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I have a user which belongs to a company.

I have a table with

```
<%= user.company.name %>
<%= user.name %>
etc.
```

Do you know how it is possible to sort my objects by the company name ?
I use sortable method from railscast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

And I really don't know how to sort by company name...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

```
@users.sort! { |a,b| a.company.name.downcase <=> b.company.name.downcase }
```